# Wordpress wp-admin screen blank in different browsers

Tags: wordpress

When I log in to Wordpress in different browsers it will show a blank page.
When I am in Chrome it will show this code:

[printscreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/svJ9D.png)

But when i am in Firefox I can acces the wordpress admin menu.

Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 0):

Try turning on WP Debug. If this is happening due to a PHP error, you will be able to see what's going on and fix the error.

Edit:

Usually the problem is in the theme (maybe in functions.php); I would try to exclude this by switching to another theme. If it's not the theme problem, it could be a problem caused by some plugin. Try disabling plug-ins one by one until the problem is resolved to find out which plug-in might be causing the problem.

Try also to add or increase the default WordPress memory limit by adding this line to wp-config.php

```
define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '128M');
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried using WP-Debug but there comes no error message.